# Change radio button value on click of a div in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I am currently trying to create a multiple choice activity in which users select one of several answers with radio buttons next to them. I have been able to get the radio buttons to change by explicitly writing out the code like so:

```
$("#choice0").on('click', function(){
    $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=0]").attr("checked","checked");
    console.log("clicked a");
});

$("#choice1").on('click', function(){
    $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=1]").attr("checked","checked");
    console.log("clicked b");
});

$("#choice2").on('click', function(){
    $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=2]").attr("checked","checked");
    console.log("clicked c");
});
```

However, I will not necessarily know how many answers there will be. When I tried to write something more flexible:

```
function setUpAwnsers(){
    for(var i = 0; i<=3 ; i++){
        console.log("#choice" + i);
        $("#choice" + i).on('click', function(){
            $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=" + i +"]").attr("checked","checked");
            console.log("clicked");
        });
    }
}
```

The console responds with "clicked" when I click the div, but the radio button does not change.

Is there something simple I am missing, or a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can we see your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind the event in a loop ,just you can add event handler using **[start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=choice]", function () { 
    var no = this.id.replace("choice","");
    $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=" + no + "]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pounzvg/4/)**

If you want with loop follow this ,But it is not good standard way

```
function setUpAwnsers(){
    for(var i = 0; i<=3 ; i++){
        console.log("#choice" + i);
     $(document).on("click","#choice" + i, function(){
             var no = this.id.replace("choice","");
            $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=" + no  +"]").prop("checked",true);
            console.log("clicked");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked demo link

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works much better, expically switching .attr with .prop

Answer (score 2):

You should not use JavaScript for that: all you need is l... Not love, but `<label>` instead of `<div>`

```
<input type="radio" id="choice1" />
<label for="choice1">The content from your div here</label>
<input type="radio" id="choice2" />
<label for="choice2">The content from your div here</label>
```

The use of labels will give you one more advantage: when user clicks on a label the click event will be emitted for the radio as well. The div solution won't give you that.

To learn more see [label reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that since you are subscribing to the click event in a for loop, and trying to use the value `i` inside the event handler, the value of `i` will always be the last value (since it is not locally scoped). Try this:

```
function setUpAwnsers(){
    for(var i = 0; i<=3 ; i++){
        console.log("#choice" + i);
        $("#choice" + i).on('click', function(i){
            $("input[name=radioAwnser][value=" + i +"]").attr("checked","checked");
            console.log("clicked");
        }.bind(null, i));
    }
}
```